# Laravel Nova BelongsTo not working when relationship method name and foreign key prefix are different

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

Belongs to relationship not working in my Nova application when relationship method name and foreign key prefix are different.

I have two tables, event & client_location with Models Event & ClientLocation

Event Model:

```
class Event extends Model
{
   public function clientLocation()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(\App\ClientLocation::class, 'location_id');
   }
}
```

ClientLocation Model:

```
class ClientLocation extends Model
{
   public function events()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(\App\Event::class, 'location_id');
   }
}
```

Nova Resource fields method for Event:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        BelongsTo::make('clientLocation'),
    ];
}
```

Any idea on how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`BelongsTo::make()` can take 3 arguments.

They are:

1. Name to display
2. Name of the relationship
3. Nova resource

In your particular case, this should work

```
BelongsTo('Events', 'clientLocation', App\Nova\ClientLocation::class)
```